# Unable to start kibana.service using systemctl

Tags: kibana, centos7, systemd

On CentOS 7, I am unable to start kibana.service using `systemct start kibana` but i am able to start the service when running `.kibana` from `\usr\share\kibana\bin\`. This is the output when `systemctl status kibana`

```
kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2018-06-05 02:04:23 CDT; 703ms ago
  Process: 2560 ExecStart=/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2560 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 05 02:04:23 trclx2002 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 05 02:04:23 trclx2002 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Jun 05 02:04:23 trclx2002 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Jun 05 02:04:23 trclx2002 systemd[1]: kibana.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 05 02:04:23 trclx2002 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for kibana.service
Jun 05 02:04:23 trclx2002 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
Jun 05 02:04:23 trclx2002 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Jun 05 02:04:23 trclx2002 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
```

Comment: have you try to start directly from terminal？

Comment: @MikeZhang Yes, i logged into the server and I am able to run it from \bin where kibana is installed but not as service using systemctl

Comment: ```journalctl -u kibana.service -r ``` can give you log detail , most of time it's the user permission setting incorrect

Comment: Please review the answer to the FAQ [Why do things behave differently under systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. I solved it from [this link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-service-fails-to-start-after-upgrading-from-4-5-1-to-5-0-0-alpha4/55022/5)

`chown kibana:kibana -R /usr/share/kibana/optimize/`

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue as mentioned above when tried ($sudo systemctl start kibana.service) to start Kibana.
Issue: Failed to start Kibana using systemctl, but works fine through bin file.
Resolution: /etc/systemd/system/kibana.service file was trying to start kibana using the 
User=kibana
Group=kibana
where either of them exists. This is resolved after creating the kibana user, kibana group and restarting kibana.
`$useradd kibana
$groupadd kibana
$usermod -a -G kibana kibana`
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to report that the following worked on my issue after also correcting in incorrectly entered IP address and it is now working as intended.

```
I experienced the same issue as mentioned above when tried ($sudo systemctl start kibana.service) to start Kibana. Issue: Failed to start Kibana using systemctl, but works fine through bin file. Resolution: /etc/systemd/system/kibana.service file was trying to start kibana using the User=kibana Group=kibana where either of them exists. This is resolved after creating the kibana user, kibana group and restarting kibana. $useradd kibana
$groupadd kibana
$usermod -a -G kibana kibana Hope this helps.
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34717548)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).